# jquery selected options multi select works once

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, select

Right I have an issue with chrome/jquery mobile. In internet explorer the script seems to run fine.

here is the  [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/7x9BT/)

The problem is when I select multiple items from BOTH lists after click it goes fine. When i do it the second time the list is not cleared anymore.

HTML code:

```
    <!-- Select Multiple -->
<div class="control-group" style="float: left;">
  <label class="control-label" for="selectmultiple">Licentie Man</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <select id="maleLicense" style="height: 210px;" name="maleLicense" class="input-medium" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="l0000000000000000000100">Amateur</option>
    <option value="l0000000000000000000001">Basislid</option>
    <option value="l0000000000000000001000">Belofte</option>
    <option value="l0000000000000000010000">Elite</option>
    <option value="l0000000000000000100000">Jeugd</option>
    <option value="l0000000000000001000000">Junior 1e jaars</option>
    <option value="l0000000000000010000000">Junior 2e jaars</option>
    <option value="l0000000000000100000000">Nieuweling 1e jaars</option>
    <option value="l0000000000001000000000">Nieuweling 2e jaars</option>
    <option value="l0000000000100000000000">Professional-A</option>
    <option value="l0000000000010000000000">Professional-B</option>
    <option value="l0000000001000000000000">Sportklasse</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  </div>

<!-- Select Multiple -->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="selectmultiple">Licentie Vrouw&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <select id="femaleLicense" style="height: 210px;" name="femaleLicense" class="input-medium" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="l0000000010000000000000">Amateur</option>
    <option value="l0000000000000000000010">Basislid</option>
    <option value="l0000000100000000000000">Belofte</option>
    <option value="l0000001000000000000000">Elite</option>
    <option value="l0000010000000000000000">Jeugd</option>
    <option value="l0000100000000000000000">Junior 1e jaars</option>
    <option value="l0001000000000000000000">Junior 2e jaars</option>
    <option value="l0010000000000000000000">Nieuweling 1e jaars</option>
    <option value="l0100000000000000000000">Nieuweling 2e jaars</option>
    <option value="l1000000000000000000000">Professional-B</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<a id="click">empty input</a>
```

Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a#click").click(function(){
    "use strict";
    $('#maleLicense').children(':selected').removeProp('selected');
    $('#femaleLicense').children(':selected').removeProp('selected');
});
});
```

A picture to show what I mean visually:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **.prop('selected', false)** instead (http://api.jquery.com/prop/), it works fine I think

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a#click").click(function(){
    $('#maleLicense').children(':selected').prop('selected', false);
    $('#femaleLicense').children(':selected').prop('selected', false);
  });
});
```

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7x9BT/3/

Answer (score 0):

Use `removeAttr` as below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a#click").click(function() {
        "use strict";
        $('#maleLicense option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
        $('#femaleLicense option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7x9BT/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `removeAttr`, I used `$("#maleLicense").val(null);` and everything worked fine.

Here is the fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/7x9BT/5/